# 1-1 correspondence between bounded invariant random variables and bounded harmonic functions

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I'm trying to understand the proof of 1-1 correspondence between a bounded invariant random variable $Z$ and a bounded harmonic function $h$ given a Markov chain $X_n$. $Z$ is invariant in a sense that $Z\circ \theta = Z$ where $\theta$ is a shift operator $\theta (\omega_0, \omega_1, \omega_2, \dots) = (\omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3, \dots)$.

This is an exercise given as Exercise 5.7.2 in Durrett's "[Probability](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf)."

It is easy to see that if a bounded random variable $Z$ is given, $h(x)= E_xZ$ defines the desired harmonic function.

I have trouble showing the converse.

Suppose $h$ is a bounded harmonic function. $h(X_n)$ is a bounded martingale. So, it converges in a.e. and in $L^1$. Let the limit be $Z$.

It is easy to show that $Z$ satisfies $h(x) = E_x Z$. So, this should define the desired 1-1 correspondence.

However, I have trouble proving the invariance of $Z$. The proof given in Revuz's "[Markov Chains](https://ericmoulines.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/revuz-d-markov-chains-0444864008.pdf)" (Prop 3.2) says it is "obvious." But, I'm not sure why it is obvious.

Any help for understanding this is very much appreciated!

Comment: It seems that it should follow from the fact that $Z$ is a limiting random variable, so it is measurable relative to the invariant sigma-field; indeed, if you move around the first $k$ indices $X_1, \ldots, X_k,$ the limit random variable $Z$ should be the same.

Comment: @William M. Thanks for your comment. I edited my post to clarify what it means to be invariant here.

Comment: The idea is the same; the limit of the sequences $(X_n)$ and $(X_{n+l})$ are the same.

Comment: @William M. Could you elaborate on why $Z \circ \theta = Z$ follows from it? Let $h(X_n) \to Z(X_0, X_1, \dots)$ and $h(X_{n+1}) \to Y(X_1, X_2, \dots)$. Then, it is obvious to see $Z(X_0, X_1, \dots) = Y(X_1, X_2, \dots)$. But why $Z=Y$ follows?

Comment: So $Z((\omega_i)_{i \geq 0}) = \lim_i \omega_i,$ clearly $Z \circ \theta = Z$ because a subsequence has the same limit as the sequence. By the way, I went to check Durret's book and I remembered why I never read it: what a horrible book! It has everything all over the place without a nice system to find things and he skips a lot while making jokes out of touch every now and then. Better read Breiman's Probability, Chung's (Durret's PhD supervisor) Probability, Ash's Real Analysis and Probability, Feller's books, etc

Comment: The canonical construction of a Markov chain uses a state space $(\mathrm{S}, \mathscr{S})$ and the sequence space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}) = \left( \mathrm{S}^\mathbf{N}, \bigotimes\limits_{n \in  \mathbf{N}} \mathscr{S} \right).$ The theorem then constructs $\mathbf{P}$ on $(\Omega, \mathscr{F})$ such that the _identity function_ $X:\Omega \to \Omega$ has the desired transition probability. In this context, you define $\theta((\omega_n)) = (\omega_{n+1})$ or equivalently $\theta((X_n)_{n \in \mathbf{N}}) = (X_{n+1})_{n \in \mathbf{N}}$...

Comment: ..since by notation $X(\omega) = \omega,$ and if $\omega = (\omega_n)$ then $X((\omega_n)) = (\omega_n)$ but also $X = (X_n)$ as $X$ is a $\mathrm{S}^\mathbf{N}$-valued random object. In sum, when $X$ is evaluated in $\omega = (\omega_n)$ then $X_n(\omega) = \omega_n.$ Of course, if you now write $\omega = (\omega_{n+1})$ then $X_n(\omega) = \omega_{n+1}$ and this amguity of writting $X_n = \omega_n$ and $X_n = \omega_{n+1}$ emerges.

Comment: @William M. I think I got your point. To write it explicitly, by letting $f((\omega)_{i\geq 0}) = \lim_i\omega_i$ and $H((x_i)_{i\geq 0}) = (h(x_i)_{i\geq 0})$ we can express desired $Z$ as $Z((X_i)_{i\geq 0}) = f(H((X_i)_{i\geq 0}))$. And, we can say $Z((X_i)_{i\geq 0}) = f(H((X_i)_{i\geq 0})) = \lim_i h(X_i) = \lim_i h(X_{i+1}) = f((h(X_{i+1}))_{i\geq 0}) = f(H(X_{i+1})_{i\geq 0})= Z((X_{i+1})_{i\geq 0})$.